# Should I memoize functions in custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I have the counter component. I encapsulated the business logic with custom hook. Should I optimize functions by means `useCallback`? If there is input onchange handler, will the situation be the same?

```
const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
};
```

↓

```
const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
}, [count]);
```

[Sand](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-glitter-ni2tw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that count and setCount came from `const [count,setCount] = useState(0)` then you should use callback in the following way so increment function stays the same during the component's life cycle:

```
const increment = useCallback(() => setCount(count => count + 1),[]);
```

You don't need to re create increment when count changes because you can pass a callback to the state setter function.

Comment: Depending on what linting tools you're using, you may get an error unless you pass `setCount` to the `deps` array, but because `setCount`'s reference is always the same, explicitly passing it as a dependency doesn't change the behavior and this is equally correct.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I assume setCount is the setter from useState, maybe older linters have trouble with it but I neer have the linter complain about a useState setter being a dependency. If you were to use `setCount(count+1)` then `count` would be a dependency but passing a callback to the setter prevents that.

Comment: Explain please where argument `count` is taken from in your code.

Comment: @bigbabyweb It's not my code but your code. I assume that count and setCount came from `const [count, setCount] = useState(0)`. The setter function from useState can receive a value: `setCount(count+1)` or a callback `setCount(count=>count+1)`.  It is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: @HMR, thanks. So `count` is taken from closure, isn't it?

Comment: @bigbabyweb With `setCount(count+1)` count comes from closure and is a dependency to useCallback so every time count changes your increment function changes as well. With `setCount(count=>count+1)` count comes from React and you it is no longer a dependency for the useCallback so increment function will not change during component's life cycle.

Comment: @HMR, am I understand rightly that my two question expressions are equivalent because they rerender every time `count` changes?

Comment: @bigbabyweb Maybe in your case when count changes then increment can change too. There are many cases where a general [onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970646/1641941) is passed to many components and you don't want all components to re render when only one of them changes.

Answer (score 5):

Every function declared within a functional component’s scope should be `memoized` or `cached` with `useCallback`. If it references to other variables or functions from the component scope it should list them in its `dependency list`. Otherwise every `prop/state` change will be recreating the function a behavior rarely used.

But remember to measure before optimizing. - Even the oficial documentation says to go easy on that.

Comment: So, should I memoize my function in the custom hook?

Comment: Could you provide the URL where the docs speak about those concepts? It will be helpful for me and other learners.

Comment: There is this amazing post: https://nikgrozev.com/2019/04/07/reacts-usecallback-and-usememo-hooks-by-example/

Comment: every function? I guess you wrong in 2023.